# Configuring SSL on Nginx Reverse Proxy for GitLab

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

I am having a small issue in my personal gitlab setup. I wanted to redirect all traffic that comes from http://gitlab.example.com to https://gitlab.example.com. SSL is indeed working on https://gitlab.example.com but has to be typed specifically. Below is my nginx conf file.

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.139:443;
    server_name gitlab.example.com;

    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/gitlab.key;


location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.139:80;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header x-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

The GitLab installation is an omnibus install. What exactly do I change in my config file to allow ssl redirection?

Comment: Worth noting that the people using this should probably keep the `https` link bookmarked, anyway. And if they start relying on their being a redirect, that could be an issue in and of itself. OTOH, [risk compensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_compensation) isn't necessarily a good argument against doing something...

Comment: Probably the more secure default would be to disable plain HTTP entirely; so that either a user gets nothing, and is forced to manually change the link and make a bookmark, or the user gets a plain HTTP response, and they know there's an attacker on the network proxying their connection. Leaving plain HTTP as an option means you can accidentally have cleartext interactions and someone else sitting on the network can passively sniff the entire thing without taking any action which would alert and IDS or show up in logs.

Comment: If this is a personal instance there shouldn't be a problem with just having port 80 not open.  This is common for services such as APIs that only support HTTPS, but with websites the HTTP -> HTTPS redirect is commonly used to be user friendly.  You don't necessarily need to be user friendly to yourself in this case.

Comment: The use case is irrelevant right now. I just wanted to know to configure nginx to allow the forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options: rewrite and HTTP 301 permanent redirect, second is more preferred:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    _;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```